# Djangoの管理サイト（admin）で外部キーにUserでフィルターをかけた状態で表示させたい

Tags: python, django

Django 1.6でadminの機能を使ってます。
Modelの外部キーにフィルターをかけた状態で表示させたいです。

Modelは

```
class Hoge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, verbose_name=u'ユーザ')
```

と

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, verbose_name=u'ユーザ')
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Hoge)
```

のように２つのHogeとBarのModelがあるときに、
admin.pyで

```
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # 略
```

で、Barを表示ています。

Barをadminで編集するときには、
[image: adminでフィルター]
このようになりますが、そこにフィルターをかけたいです。

一応やれそうな方法で、

```
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BarForm
```

とし、BarFormを

```
class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # なぜかできない・・・・
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        # 略
```

としましたが、kwargsにはrequestのキーが無いため、
今アクセスしているuserを取得できません。

ご教示よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

`Bar`の`questions`Fieldをrequest.userでfilterしたい場合は、かきのとおりになるでしょうか？

```
class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "questions":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Hoge.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return super(BarAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey